# Do I need to pay taxes if I receive money from my family (foreign country) in UK?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, international-transfer, gift-tax

Actually this is for my sister, she lives in London and I want to send her money from USA to her bank account.
Will that transfer affect the taxes she must pay?

Comment: What are both your nationalities?

Comment: @JanDoggen italian, but my sister is living in London and paying taxes there.

Comment: On top of that, have you ever domiciled (read: lived a long time) in UK before?

Comment: @B.Liu not me, but my sister was living there for the last 6 years

Answer (score 1):

As long as you give the gift (of cash) more than seven years before you die or the amount is less than the annual allowance of £3,000, this will be tax-free for her.

If you die earlier than that, the gift will be subject to Inheritance Tax.

Comment: Hi, I thought that is only the case if the OP (who sends the money) is a domiciled entity in the UK? https://www.gov.uk/inheritance-tax/when-someone-living-outside-the-uk-dies